# is it possible to build a turing machine that programs a given API?

Tags: nlp, theory, turing-machines

I was wondering, is it possible to define an API and give it as an input to a `TM` turing machine and the output will be the code in `c` or any other natural/programming language?

I guess not but how do I show it formally by reduction etc. ?

Comment: Why would it be impossible? The very definition of a turing-complete programming language is that it can simulate turing machines.

Comment: since if it possible why there are programmers who's salary is 300k$ a year?

Comment: Possible != feasible. Also, turing machines don't pop out of nowhere.

Comment: Because there isn't a Turing machine that can understand incompletely specified requirements, that's what humans can do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question seems to be asking if it is possible to write a program (in other words, a Turing Machine) that takes in a program specification (what you are calling an "API") and outputs a program in some programming language.  The answer to this is "of course".  Let's look at a few examples.

1. Let's say I write my input specification as a C program and I want to output a program in C.  I call this Turing Machine program "copy" and I can trivially implement it in any language (or use the `cp` command on the command line).
2. Let's say I write my input specification as a C program, and I want to output a program in assembly code.  I call this Turing Machine program "compiler" and I can implement it in any language (or you can download a C compiler that already exists).
3. Let's say I write my input specification in English and I want to output a program in C.  I call this Turing Machine program "software engineer" and I implement it in the brain of a human by sending that human to school (or you can hire an existing software engineer).

The moral here is that a Turing Machine can do anything that a human can do (and a human can do anything a Turing Machine can do).  But it's really, really, really hard to write a computer program that is as general-purpose as a human.

Comment: I don't think you can answer that question until you figure out exactly what you are imagining as your input, your output, and your algorithm.